# At a language level, what exactly is `ccall`?

Tags: function, syntax, macros, julia, ffi

I'm new to Julia, and I'm trying to understand, at the language level, what [`ccall`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/c/) is. At the syntax level, it looks like a normal function, but it clearly doesn't behave the same way in how it takes its arguments:

> Note that the argument type tuple must be a literal tuple, and not a
>   tuple-valued variable or expression.

Additionally, if I evaluate a variable bound to a function in the Julia REPL, I get something like

```
julia> max
max (generic function with 15 methods)
```

But if I try to do the same with `ccall`:

```
julia> ccall
ERROR: syntax: invalid "ccall" syntax
```

Clearly, `ccall` is a special piece of syntax, but it's also not a macro (no `@` prefix, and invalid macro usage gives a more specific error). So, *what is it*? Is it something baked into the language, or something I could define myself with some language construct I'm not familiar with?

And if it is some baked-in piece of syntax, why was it decided to use function call notation, instead of implementing it as a macro or designing a more readable and distinct syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the current nightly (and thus, upcoming 0.6 release), much of the special behavior you observe [has been removed](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/91f9e821) (see [this pull-request](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/18754)). `ccall` is no longer a reserved word, so it can be used as a function or macro name.

*However* there is still a slight oddity: defining a 3- or 4-argument function called `ccall` is allowed, but actually calling such a function will give an error about `ccall argument types` (other numbers of arguments are ok). The reasons go directly to your question:

> So, what is it? Is it something baked into the language

Yes, `ccall`, though it will no longer be a keyword in 0.6, is still "baked in" to the language in several ways:

- the `:ccall([four args...])` expression form is recognized and [specially handled](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/cb1aae9aef4eedec839dc246c87a00e9463efa6c/src/julia-syntax.scm#L914-L938) during syntax lowering. This lowering step does several things including wrapping arguments in a call to `unsafe_convert`, which allows for customized conversion from Julia objects to C-compatible objects; as well as pulling out arguments that might need to be [rooted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection) to prevent garbage collection of a referenced object during the `ccall`. (see `code_lowered` output, or try the `expand` function; more info on the compiler [here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/devdocs/julia/)).
- `ccall` requires [extensive handling](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/cb1aae9aef4eedec839dc246c87a00e9463efa6c/src/ccall.cpp) in the code generation backend, including: look-up of the requested function name in the specified shared library, and generation of an LLVM [`call`](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#call-instruction) instruction -- which is eventually translated to platform-specific machine code by the LLVM Just-In-Time compiler. (see the different stages with `code_llvm` and `code_native`).

> And if it is some baked-in piece of syntax, why was it decided to use
>   function call notation, instead of implementing it as a macro or
>   designing a more readable and distinct syntax?

For the reasons detailed above, `ccall` requires special handling whether it looks like a macro or a function. In [this mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/julia-users/b8qLRruRkN0/3Et_cBHV5FIJ), one of the Julia creators (Stefan Karpinski) commented on why not to make it a macro:

> I suppose we could reimplement it as a macro, but that would really just be pushing the magic further down.

As far as "a more readable and distinct syntax", perhaps that is a matter of taste. It's not clear to me why some other syntax would be preferable (except for the convenience of a LuaJIT/CFFI-style inline C syntax parsing, of which I am a fan). My only strong personal wish for `ccall` would be to have arguments and types entered adjacent (e.g. `ccall((:foo, :libbar), Void, (x::Int, y::Float))`), because working with longer argument lists can be inconvenient. In 0.6 it will be possible to implement this form as a macro!

Comment: The `ccall` special form also predates macros in the language: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/18f456233b280f2b5649c033c1977133c73bfd88 vs. https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/a1b9fee4e72e8438693eddc25d769fab4cc98c9d. There was an earlier macro system (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/3e6fcd19b805f0fbc713a06a3e6ddb3f88da1b89) but I don't think it was capable of expressing what `ccall` requires. That probably hasn't been possible until Jameson Nash's recent work to "de-magic" ccall.

Answer (score 4):

In Julia 0.5 and earlier.
It is not a function and it is not a macro.
It is indeed something special baked into the language.
It is an Intrinsic.
[In julia 0.6 this changes](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/18754)

It a lot of ways it is more like a Macro than a function call.
But in other ways it is not -- it does not return an AST.
It does call a function and on a low enough level it looks similar to calling a julia function.

The history of why it looks the way it does is beyond me, you'ld need to hear from one of the people who worked on the earliest code for the language.
Right now it is everywhere, and is one of the harder things to change -- but not impossible. [It would trigger up for 3 years of bikeshedding though :-P](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4774) .

I like to think of `ccall` as being two things.

- Foreign Function Interface, for C and other compiled languages (eg Fortran, Rust apparently work)
- Way to access the raw guts of the language "runtime".

#### Foreign Function Interface (FFI)

Most of the time when one uses `ccall` in a package one wants to invoke some code that is in a compile library. In this sense it is C-Call, like R-Call, or Py-Call.
I think [mlewe/BlossomV.jl](https://github.com/mlewe/BlossomV.jl/blob/master/src/BlossomV.jl) is a nice compact example.
For a more intense example [oxinabox/SLEEF.jl](https://github.com/oxinabox/SLEEF.jl/blob/master/src/sleef_inner.jl).

As an FFI, it does not have to share memory space/a process with julia -- PyCall.jl does, RCall.jl and Matlab.jl don't.
It doesn't matter as long as the result comes back.
In these cases it is theoretically possible to replace `ccall` with some kind of `safe_ccall` which would run the called library in a separate process, and would not segfault julia if the library being called segfaulted.
But as of yet, no-one has written such a method/package.

Using `ccall` for FFI is even done in Base, like for accessing [MPFR to define BigFloat](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/cb1aae9aef4eedec839dc246c87a00e9463efa6c/base/mpfr.jl).
But this is not the main reason `ccall` is used in `Base`.

#### Accessing the guts of the language.

`ccall` is really what drives a large portion of the program "doing a thing".
It is used throughout [Base](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/tree/master/base), to call the functions from [src](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/tree/master/src).

For this, `ccall` basically triggers a function call at the compiled level, that shifts the instruction pointer directly into the compiled code of the `ccall`ed function. Like calling a function would if the whole thing had been written in say C.

You can see in [base/threadingconstructs.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/cb1aae9aef4eedec839dc246c87a00e9463efa6c/base/threadingconstructs.jl#L57) ccall being used to manage work on threads -- that triggers code from [src/threading.c](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/cb1aae9aef4eedec839dc246c87a00e9463efa6c/src/threading.c#L769).

It is used to map a section of disk to memory. [mmap.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/v0.5.0/base/mmap.jl#L97). -- obviously can't be done from another process.

It is used to make a section of code [non-intruptable](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/v0.5.0/base/c.jl#L411)

It is used call [LibC](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) to do things like `malloc` to allocate memory (though right now this is mostly used as part of FFI).

There are tricks you can do with `ccall` to `#undef` a variable after it has already been assigned.
`ccall` is in many ways the "master" key to the language.

#### Conclusion

I've described `ccall` here as two things, a FFI function and a core part of the language "runtime". This duality is not real, and there is plenty of overlap, like filehandling (is it FFI?).
The behavour many expect ccall to have comes from its FFI uses.
Here ccall could just be a function.
The behaviour it actually has comes from it's use as a core part of the language -- linking the julia code of the standard library in [Base](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/tree/master/base) to the low level C code from [src](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/tree/master/src).
Allowing the very direct control over the running of the julia process.

Comment: This answer could be enhanced by showing what a `ccall` becomes in LLVM and ASM.